# Reuse SVG images while maintaining css control

Tags: html, css, svg

I have some silhouette type images and they need to be able to change color, sometimes just to display in different locations, sometimes for hover effects.

This is easy enough to do with the SVG directly embedded into the HTML. Copy-paste and CSS to your heart's desire.

But then I have to copy-paste or programatically insert everywhere I want it. Some of these are used dozens of times. It just seems poor practice to re-transmit the same SVG markup repeatedly.

Is there a best-of-both-worlds solution, where I can CSS the paths and also somehow reuse the SVG on the front-end?

Comment: There is a <use> tag in svg that let's you reuse "symbols". I think that is as close as you'll get. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/

Comment: @ippi that's exactly what I needed. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a  tag in svg that let's you reuse "symbols". I think that is as close as you'll get.

You create a symbol by wrapping your paths etc in a symbol-element. Give it an id (so you can re-use it later):

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="ic">
      <paths and polygons and other fun stuff>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Now you can reuse this symbol with `<use>` and `xlink:href` pointing to the symbol you made. And you can add classes freely to change things up:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#ic" class="ic-blue"  x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

Examples and code shamelessly plucked from https://tympanus.net/codrops Go read their content and click their ads! If there ever was a site deserving an exception in your ad-blocker, this is it.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
use.ic-1 {
  fill: skyblue;
}
use.ic-2 {
  fill: #FDC646;
}
use.ic-3 {
  fill: #FF2D49;
}

svg path {
  fill: inherit;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="ic">
    <path fill="#000000" d="M81,40.933c0-4.25-3-7.811-6.996-8.673c-0.922-5.312-3.588-10.178-7.623-13.844  c-2.459-2.239-5.326-3.913-8.408-4.981c-0.797-3.676-4.066-6.437-7.979-6.437c-3.908,0-7.184,2.764-7.979,6.442  c-3.078,1.065-5.939,2.741-8.396,4.977c-4.035,3.666-6.701,8.531-7.623,13.844C22.002,33.123,19,36.682,19,40.933  c0,2.617,1.145,4.965,2.957,6.589c0.047,0.195,0.119,0.389,0.225,0.568l26.004,43.873c0.383,0.646,1.072,1.04,1.824,1.04  c0.748,0,1.439-0.395,1.824-1.04L77.82,48.089c0.105-0.179,0.178-0.373,0.225-0.568C79.855,45.897,81,43.549,81,40.933z   M49.994,11.235c2.164,0,3.928,1.762,3.928,3.93c0,2.165-1.764,3.929-3.928,3.929s-3.928-1.764-3.928-3.929  C46.066,12.997,47.83,11.235,49.994,11.235z M27.842,36.301c0.014,0,0.027,0,0.031,0c1.086,0,1.998-0.817,2.115-1.907  c0.762-7.592,5.641-13.791,12.303-16.535c1.119,3.184,4.146,5.475,7.703,5.475c3.561,0,6.588-2.293,7.707-5.48  c6.664,2.742,11.547,8.944,12.312,16.54c0.115,1.092,1.037,1.929,2.143,1.907c2.541,0.013,4.604,2.087,4.604,4.631  c0,1.684-0.914,3.148-2.266,3.958H25.508c-1.354-0.809-2.268-2.273-2.268-3.958C23.24,38.389,25.303,36.316,27.842,36.301z   M50.01,86.723L27.73,49.13h44.541L50.01,86.723z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use class="ic-1" xlink:href="#ic" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use class="ic-2" xlink:href="#ic" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use class="ic-3" xlink:href="#ic" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```